# Variable length substring between two characters

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Data looks like this:

```
Initiative: Credible Sources;
Initiative: Just in Time;
Initiative: Database Normalization;
```

I want it to look like this:

```
Credible Sources
Just in Time
Database Normalization
```

It's pretty simple to get rid of one or the other.

This:

```
SELECT DISTINCT LEFT(OPTIONAL_FIELD_2, CHARINDEX(';', OPTIONAL_FIELD_2 + ';')-1) AS OPTIONAL_FIELD_2
FROM my_table
ORDER BY OPTIONAL_FIELD_2
```

Gives me this:
Initiative: Credible Sources
Initiative: Just in Time
Initiative: Database Normalization

And this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT RIGHT(OPTIONAL_FIELD_2, LEN(OPTIONAL_FIELD_2)-12) AS OPTIONAL_FIELD_2
FROM my_table
ORDER BY OPTIONAL_FIELD_2
```

Gives me this:

```
Credible Sources;
Just in Time;
Database Normalization;
```

Having a hard time figuring out how to combine the two.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about just using `substring()`?

```
select replace(substring(option_field_2, 13, 999), ';', '')
```

Or, if you don't know how long the prefix is:

```
select replace(stuff(option_field_2, 1, charindex(':', option_field_2) + 1, ''), ';', '')
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=0a4328a1dc9c58284ce126a5a5032204) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: Thanks, @gordon-linoff, it works a treat. I tend to overthink things and it's usually a simple solution :)